# Reading the values between " and \

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string like `"X[2] <= 17055.5\ngini = 0.0454\nsamples = 43\nvalue = [42, 1]"`

I want to read `X[2] <= 17055.5`
Any help would be appreciated, I know It is done using python regex. I am new to that topic.

Comment: `your_str.splitlines()[0]` will give you the same result

Comment: Just in case the `"` is actually in the string, you can do `my_str.strip('"').split('\n')[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need Regex for this. Simple `str.split('\n')` and taking the 0-th indexed value would do:

```
str_.split('\n')[0]
```

Or use `str.splitlines()` which would split on newlines (thanks @Moinuddin Quadri for reminding):

```
str_.splitlines()[0]
```

**Example:**

```
In [17]: s = "X[2] <= 17055.5\ngini = 0.0454\nsamples = 43\nvalue = [42, 1]"

In [18]: s.split('\n')[0]
Out[18]: 'X[2] <= 17055.5'

In [19]: s.splitlines()[0]
Out[19]: 'X[2] <= 17055.5'
```

---

As a side note, for text-processing, you should pick `re` methods only when the `str` methods are not enough.

Comment: or you may just do `str_.splitlines()[0]`. By default `.splitlines()` splits on `\n`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Sure. Added.

Comment: Thank You, How about if I have a big string with multiple " " and I want to read all the values in " " in new line. E.g

Comment: @Ara Could you please give an example input and desired output?

Comment: @Ara Ummm...you should ask this as a new question as this one has been answered.

Comment: I have a big string , and want o read all values between " " for e.g `{\nnode [shape=box] ;\n0 [label="X[2] <= 17055.5\\ngini = 0.0454\\nsamples = 43\\nvalue = [42, 1]"] ;\n1 [label="gini = 0.0\\nsamples = 1\\nvalue = [0, 1]"] ;\n0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;\n2 [label="gini = 0.0\\nsamples = 42\\nvalue = [42, 0]"] ;\n0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;\n}` Here I should have three outputs , because there are three strings between " "

Comment: @Ara: `re.findall(r'(?<=")[^"]+(?=")', str_)` ?

Comment: I want to avoid the "True" and "False"

Comment: @Ara `re.findall(r'(?<=")(?!\]|True|False)[^"]+(?=")', str_)`

Comment: How about, printing all the elements right to <=     There may be multiple appearnces of <=

Comment: I asked as a new question

Answer (score 0):

That looks a lot like a simple string, so that should be working:

```
>>> for elem in "X[2] <= 17055.5\ngini = 0.0454\nsamples = 43\nvalue = [42, 1]".splitlines():
...     print(elem)
...
X[2] <= 17055.5
gini = 0.0454
samples = 43
value = [42, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
str = "X[2] <= 17055.5\ngini = 0.0454\nsamples = 43\nvalue = [42, 1]"
print(str.split('\n'))
```